# How to handle permission inside a volume from docker?

Tags: php, docker, file-permissions, docker-compose, mounted-volumes

I have a container running a PHP application and the `php-fpm` service can't write the cache files inside an folder provided by a docker volume.

I gave 777 permissions on the folder I need to write, from the host machine, but it works just for a while. Files created by `php-fpm` doesn't have necessary permissions. 
Furthermore it's not possible to change the owner and group with `chown` command.

This is my `docker-composer.yml` file:

```
web:
    image: eduardoleal/nginx
    external_links:
        - proxy
    links:
        - php:php
    container_name: "app-web"
    environment:
        VIRTUAL_HOST: web.app
    volumes_from:
        - data 
    volumes:
        - ./src/nginx-vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
php:
    image: eduardoleal/php56
    container_name: "app-web-php"
    volumes_from:
        - data
data:
    container_name: "app-web-data" 
    image: phusion/baseimage
    volumes:
        - /Users/eduardo.leal/Code/vidaclass/web:/var/www/public
```

I'm running docker on OSX with VirtualBox.

Comment: For now I could resolve following this gist: https://gist.github.com/haggen/f84f55e3ed2c9c930335.
But i think it`s a quick fix.

Comment: That is an old post, for newer systems, I have added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacOS has some mounting problems because of the differences in `user` and `group` owning the file versus `user` and `group` modifying/reading the file. As a workaround, do the following (preferably using the latest version) of Docker,

```
$ brew install docker-machine-nfs
$ docker-machine start yourdockermachine
$ docker-machine-nfs yourdockermachine --shared-folder=/Users --nfs-config="-alldirs -maproot=0"
```

You can change the name of `yourdockermachine` as you like. Also, you have the ability to change the shared folder you want to map. The above option is the best bet and works in all cases. I would suggest not changing that so that you don't mess around with system files.

After the above setup, make sure you provide appropriate read, write, execute permissions to your files and folders.

**NOTE**: Dependencies for above procedure are `brew`, `docker-machine` (or the complete docker toolbox for simplicity)

**UPDATE 1**: [Docker for Mac Beta](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/) is in private invite phase. It runs Docker natively on Mac on top of **xhyve Hypervisor**. It would mean, no more permission errors and improved performance.

**UPDATE 2**: [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/) is now in Public Beta. The underlying technology remains the same and the VM is completely managed by the Docker service. The version as of this writing is `1.12.0-rc2` which works seamlessly with OS X without any intervention of `docker-machine`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Worked perfectly!

Comment: @EduardoLeal Please have a look at the update. Let me know if you get an invite. Could probably update the answer sometime.

Comment: Worked with -mapall=502:20 setting. where 502:20 is user id and group id of current osx user.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. Docker machine uses `docker` user and `staff` group on mounted volumes, which have `UID=1000` and `GID=50` respectively. You need to modify your `php-fpm` config and replace default user (I suppose it's `nobody`), with username which have `UID=1000` **inside container**. In case you don't have such user, you'll need to create such user. Do the same trick for group with `GID=50`. It's very-very dirty hack, but I didn't found better solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MacOSx. you have to change permission of staff user (this user is created by docker). Default staff user only read permission. So webserver cannot write into your cache folder in docker container. You can do and see the picture below

[image]

chmod -R 777 cache_folder on your mac.

Hope this answer is useful for you

Anyway, you can also use docker-machine-nfs to fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

Add `RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data` somewhere before EXPOSE into Dockerfile for eduardoleal/php56 image, it will fix problem with permissions.